# Xamarin forms picker on background clicked

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-controls, picker

I have a custom picker with this code in PCL and android that are shown below.

https://xamgirl.com/picker-with-right-side-icon-in-xamarin-forms/

The problem is when I open the picker and press on the background the picker will not open again. I tried to press ok and cancel the picker will act normally and can get focus again

Is there a way to handle the background click to the picker to prevent it from popping unless I click on cancel or ok?

PCL:

```
   using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace AppXamarin
{
    public class CustomPicker : Picker
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty ImageProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Image), typeof(string), typeof(CustomPicker), string.Empty);
        public string Image
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Android:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using AppXamarin;
using AppXamarin.Droid;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace AppXamarin.Droid
{
    public class CustomPickerRenderer : PickerRenderer
    {
        CustomPicker element;
        public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            AutoPackage = false;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            element = (CustomPicker)this.Element;

            if (Control != null && this.Element != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Image))
            {
                Control.Background = AddPickerStyles(element.Image);   
            }
        }
        public LayerDrawable AddPickerStyles(string imagePath)
        {
            ShapeDrawable border = new ShapeDrawable();
            border.Paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Gray;
            border.SetPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            border.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);

            Drawable[] layers = { border, GetDrawable(imagePath) };
            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
            layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            return layerDrawable;
        }
        private BitmapDrawable GetDrawable(string imagePath)
        {
            //int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(imagePath, "drawable", this.Context.PackageName);
            var drawable = Resources.GetDrawable(imagePath);
            var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;
            var result = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true));
            result.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Add your code let me take a look

Comment: My code is same as in the URL in my question, but I edited my question with the code of PCL and android renders

Comment: SO what happens is, you click on the picker it opens and the next time you click it doesn't?

Comment: first time I click it opens, when I click on ok or cancel, the next time I click it opens normally. But when I click on the background of the picker it will close and when I try to open it again it will not open. If you got confused I can try to rephrase what I said

Comment: I understood your issue, is it happening in android or iOS both

Comment: for now, I'm testing on Android. I will check it on iOS nad give you the feedback

Comment: Waiting let me know

Comment: @mohammad,I try your code , but I can not reproduce your issue, can you provide one .gif here, let me take a look your issue, What is the Xamarin.Forms version?

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two PickerRenderer's the `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer` and the basic `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android` one, the basic one has this issue what you actually need to do is something like for you Android Renderer:

```cs
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using AppXamarin;
using AppXamarin.Droid;
using Plugin.CurrentActivity;
using Xamarin.Forms;


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomPicker), typeof(CustomPickerRenderer))]
namespace AppXamarin.Droid
{
     public class CustomPickerRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer
    {
        private CustomPicker element;
        public CustomPickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            AutoPackage = false;
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            element = (CustomPicker)this.Element;

            if (Control != null && this.Element != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Image))
            {
                Control.Background = AddPickerStyles(element.Image);
            }
        }
        public LayerDrawable AddPickerStyles(string imagePath)
        {
            ShapeDrawable border = new ShapeDrawable();
            border.Paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Gray;
            border.SetPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
            border.Paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);

            Drawable[] layers = { border, GetDrawable(imagePath) };
            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
            layerDrawable.SetLayerInset(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

            return layerDrawable;
        }
        private BitmapDrawable GetDrawable(string imagePath)
        {
            //int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(imagePath, "drawable", this.Context.PackageName);
            var drawable = Resources.GetDrawable(imagePath);
            var bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;
            var result = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true));
            result.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one: Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer is giving me errors: "onElementChanged" and "var drawable = Resources.GetDrawable(imagePath);" that can't be fixed

Comment: Updated take a look

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it by downgrading my Xamarin.Forms version, I had a pre-release version installed. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: to which version did you downgrade?

Comment: to version : 3.4.0.1008975

Answer (score 0):

just inherit following,it's working fine for me

public class CustomPickerRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.PickerRenderer